# Компиляция шаблона

Tags: angularjs, компиляция

Есть шаблон

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 page-feed">
        <div class="box {{_id}}">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="{{user.photo}}" alt="Jane" />
            </div>
            <div class="page-feed-content">
                <small class="time">{{user.name}}, {{rebuildDate(date)}}</small>
                <p>{{comment}}</p>
                <div class="likebox">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li ng-click="like(_id,$event)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span class="likes">{{likes}}</span></li>
                            <li ng-click="dislike(_id,$event)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> <span class="dislikes">{{dislikes}}</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И код на *AngulaJS*:

```js
       $scope.$on('commentsAfterAdd',function(event, data){
            $http.get('views/post.html').then(function(html){
                for(var item in data.collection)
                    $scope[item] = data.collection[item];

                var template = angular.element(html.data);
                var element = $compile(template)($scope);
              document.body.querySelector('[class="commentsList"]').innerHTML += element.html();
            });
        });
```

Если после `$compile` я делаю

```js
console.info(element)
```

То вижу следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть, компиляция происходит успешно, но есть проблема.
Строка:

```
document.body.querySelector('[class="commentsList"]').innerHTML += element.html();
```

вставляет на страницу исходный шаблон.

Уже и `InnerHTML` пробовал, и `element[0]`, не помогает.
В объекте все ок, а нормальный *HTML* получить не могу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста: как быть?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` - это свойство элемента, которое возвращает или задаёт строку `string`.

Возьмём например такой код:

```
element.innerHTML += "<div>test</div>";
```

Это то же самое, что и

```
var html = element.innerHTML;
html += "<div>test</div>";
element.innerHTML = html;
```

Обращаю внимание, что в переменной `html` уже находятся не элементы, а **строка**. Далее к **строке** прибавляем другую строчку, и присваиваем свойству innerHTML. В итоге, в element уже встроены совсем другие элементы, с другими событиями и свойствами.

В вашем случае - вы скомпилировали шаблон сервисом `$compile`, а следующей же строчкой скомпилированный шаблон превращаете в строку, создаёте по строке *новые* элементы и встраиваете их в `[class="commentsList"]`.

Более того, innerHTML - пожалуй самая ресурсоёмкая операция при работе с DOM, если можно, то её следует избегать всегда.

В вашем случае надо пользоваться функциями для встраивания элементов в DOM-дерево, такие как `appendChild` для нативного JS или `append` в jQuery.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!